# Where are clitics initially Merged in Italian?

Tags: italian, minimalism, clitics

I'm trying to port Cardinaletti & Shlonsky's [analysis of Italian clitic placement](http://www.unige.ch/lettres/linguistique/shlonsky/readings/Restructuring.pdf)<sup>1</sup> to the Minimalist framework for a term paper. The course is based on Adger's textbook<sup>2</sup> which mostly focuses on syntax trees of English sentences.

I'm trying to represent simple sentences like `Io ci vado` and `Io voglio andarci` using syntax trees. In the first sentence, the locative clitic *ci* is in a clausal position, and in the second sentence it is attached to the lexical verb.

My intuition is that *ci* is initially merged as *andare*'s complement in VP, but I'm not sure if it's possible to move the clitic to an entirely new projection (LocCL)—between T and vP—later in the derivation to account for the word order in the first sentence.

I'm not entirely sure how I'd motivate that movement either since clitic climbing is optional.

```
Io ci    vado.
I  there go
'I go there.'

Io voglio andarci.
I  want   (to) go.there
'I want to go there.'
```

Where are clitics initially Merged in Italian?

[1] Cardinaletti, A., & Shlonsky, U. (2004). Clitic positions and restructuring in Italian. *Linguistic Inquiry*, *35*(4), 519-557.

[2] Adger, D. (2003). *Core syntax: a minimalist approach*. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Answer (score -2):

I Start saying I'm Italian, so I tell you things that can make a good Italian.
So, In Italian often there isn't the subject as Io (I), Tu (you), Lui (he) etc.
You can say:

```
Ci    vado.

Voglio andarci.
```

Last thing, In Italian there = li/là, So, you can also say;

```
Io vado li/là.

Io voglio andare li/là.
```

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics.SE! Unfortunately the poster is looking for a Minimalist Program analysis of Italian pronoun clitics, and not general information.